# Why am I not able to see close options on every question?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a “closed” question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question)

To see a close tab on every question, one needs 250 reputation. I have enough reputation on Stack Overflow (i.e., greater than 2000), but I'm still not able to see the close link. Why is this so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need [at least **3000** reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/close-questions) to see close votes on, and vote to close, other people's questions. The 250-reputation milestone limits you to [accessing close votes on your own questions](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/view-close-votes).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response..
I was checking the `View close votes` privileges.